# Block git force push for all branches

Tags: git, scmmanager

I m using SCM-Manager(GIT).

I wish to block the force push option in a repository named "git_playground" for all branches in the remote

I'm not sure where the below config to set in the git server

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

I have tried to set the above confi in 
config file of the repository under `[core]` as

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards =  true
```

After this i cannot be able to clone that repository .
So revoked it.

Comment: **Don't** manually modify Git configuration files. Use [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Answer (score 1):

Not `[core]`:

```
[receive]
denyNonFastForwards = true
```

To avoid such troubles edit config with command line:

```
git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

Comment: do we need any restart after this changes done ? i have added that , but still force push  is working .  followed the `git config` command

Comment: Restart? Probably? The config command must be given at the server either in a repository (in every repo you want to protect) or globally: `git config --global receive.denyNonFastForwards true`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the SCM-Manager configuration option **Disallow Non Fast-Forward** (available since version 1.55) at **Config->Repository Types->Git**. If this option is enabled SCM-Manager will block every force push. But this option is global and affects every repository on the SCM-Manager instance.

Comment: mine is 1.51 :(